# Getting rid of few entities using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Regex.  Given the below phrase I want to get rid of the I's and the extra field appearing because of using two regex operation.

```
text= "I have a problem in Regex, How do I get rid of the Capital I's provided I want to retain words occurring together as logical entity with a Capital letter in the beginning of each word like International Business Machine "
```

For example 
   I would like to retain "International Business Machine" as "International Business Machine" and not "Capital I's" as "Capital I's" but "Capital"

I used the below Regular Expression:

```
re.findall('([A-Z][\w\']*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w|\']*)+)|([A-Z][\w]*)', text)
```

The output I received is

```
[('', 'I'),
 ('', 'Regex'),
 ('', 'How'),
 ('', 'I'),
 ("Capital I's", ''),
 ('', 'I'),
 ('', 'Capital'),
 ('International Business Machine', '')]
```

However I would Like my Output to be as :

```
[('Regex'),
 ('How'),
 ("Capital"),
 ('Capital'),
 ('International Business Machine')]
```

How do I get rid of the "I" and the extra field appearing because of using two regex operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match also apostrophes(like in your example), you can try with:

```
(?:[A-Z](?:[\w]|(?<=\w\w)\')+\s?)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tT4oY1/3)

it will match `'` if it is preceded by at least two word characters. Not too fancy solution but works. Then:

```
import re
text = 'I have a problem in Regex, How do I get rid of the Capital I\'s provided I want to retain words occurring together as logical entity with a Capital letter in the beginning of each word like International Business Machine'
found = re.findall('(?:[A-Z](?:[\w]|(?<=\w\w)\')+\s?)+',text)
print found
```

will also give a result:

```
['Regex', 'How ', 'Capital ', 'Capital ', 'International Business Machine']
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, it does, but it seems that for OP the apostrophes matching was decisive

Answer (score 2):

Just match the word which starts with a captital letter followed by one or more word characters and then add a pattern to match the following words which should be like the previous one(*starts with captital letter*) and make that pattern to repeat zero or more times. So that it would match strings like `Foo` or `Foo Bar Buzz`.

```
>>> text= "I have a problem in Regex, How do I get rid of the Capital I's provided I want to retain words occurring together as logical entity with a Capital letter in the beginning of each word like International Business Machine "
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w+(?:\s+[A-Z]\w+)*', text)
['Regex', 'How', 'Capital', 'Capital', 'International Business Machine']
```

Comment: `[A-Z]\B\w*` implies `[A-Z]\w+`

Comment: I think you should just remove the old solution and add an explanation for the new solution.